# LinkedIn not reading JSON request

Tags: json, xml, linkedin-api

Trying to 'share' on LinkedIn: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

Which is basically a POST to 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json'
in its simplest form is with json:

```
{
  "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com! http://linkd.in/1FC2PyG",
  "visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
  }
}
```

This requires setting http headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
x-li-format: json
```

I'm trying to do this using OAuth.io, but LinkedIn seems to be still reading the body in XML.

See my example here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lv3jtpkb/2/

I get the following error from it:

`Invalid xml {Element &#39;share@http://api.linkedin.com/v1&#39; with element-only content type cannot have text content.}`

I have checked if from OAuth.io server to LinkedIn API endpoint the headers specified here at frontend were somehow altered and can confirm that they have not been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. There are 2 errors.

1. Your data are formatted as a JS object. The method you're using doesn't seem to be converting the object to JSON automatically.
2. This line of code isn't doing anything, and is causing exceptions:

   ```
   .then(user => { console.log("next:",user) })
   ```

   Remove it.

Working code snippet:

```
$('#linkedin-button').on('click', function() {
// Initialize with your OAuth.io app public key
OAuth.initialize('A5oDtHv-oUEVlR7q7hDolXxC7RE');
  alert('init');
  OAuth.popup('linkedin2').then(linkedin => {
  alert('logged in');
    linkedin.post({
      url: "/v1/people/~/shares?format=json",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        "comment": "Hello world!",
        "visibility": {
          "code": "anyone"
        }
      }),
      headers: {
         "x-li-format": "json",
         "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).then(data => {
      console.log("success:", data);
      }).fail(err => { console.log("err:",err) });
  })
})
```

Success in console:
[image]